# Getting the source term that a Regex matches to

Tags: regex, angularjs

I am creating a "highlighter" filter in AngularJS to highlight search terms in a results table.  For example, the user searches "Foo" and gets back a bunch of results.  Our results are case-insensitive so most results may come back with "foo" in it.  I created a regex object to capture any "foo" with case-insensitivity like this:

```
app.filter('highlighter', function(){
   return function(input, term){
       input = input || '';
       if(!term || term === ''){
           return input;
       }

       var re = new RegExp(term,"i")

       input = input.replace(re, '<strong>'+re.source+'</strong>');

       return input;




   }

});
```

The only problem is that then I run my replace, it replaces all "foo"s with "Foo" in the search results, but I want to replace it with "foo".  Basically I want to access the term that was matched in the `input`. So if `input` is "/Documents/foobar/test.docx" then a search for "Foo" should cause the `input` to become "/Documents/**foo**bar/test.docx".  Right now, it is instead using the actually term so it is returning "/Documents/**Foo**bar/test.docx", which is incorrect.

Comment: So, you want at lowercased version of `re.source`? Or is your problem that you want the primitive that re.source should be, regardless of case?

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want?

```
function(input, term) {
   input = input || '';
   if (typeof term === 'undefined' || !term || !input) { return input; }
   input = input.replace(new RegExp('('+term+')','ig'),'<strong>$1</strong>');
   return input;
}
```

The `g` flag matches more than one occurrence.
Test case:

```
var term='xxx';console.log('aaaXxXbBbxXxccc'.replace(new RegExp('('+term+')','ig'),'<strong>$1</strong>'));
```

yields:

```
aaa<strong>XxX</strong>bBb<strong>xXx</strong>ccc
```